# What software can I use to typeset proofs for my class?

Tags: math-software

I'm taking a class on proofs this semester. My first assignment is to prove propositions using axioms. Is there software I can use to type these mathematical symbols and equations?

Comment: Do you want software that allows you to *typset* the homework, or to *solve* the homework?

Comment: I can solve the homework, just want a software that can type mathematically. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: This sounds like a great question to *direct to your instructor*.

Comment: I suggest LaTeX, it is free and this site uses it to write math too

Comment: If you think this is something you want to be doing for a while (so, if you're a math major or something), I recommend you learn LaTex.  If this is just for this class, it may be easier to learn LyX.

Both of these are markup languages (like HTML) that allow you to typset math.  As an example, I can type "P \implies Q" to get that $P\implies Q$, or "A^c\cup B^c = (A\cap B)^c" to get that $A^c\cup B^c = (A\cap B)^c$.

Comment: yes you can use latex, even if you have some difficulties about latex, you can ask here, dont worry, may be some people will type some harsh comments to your questions (if your questions are too noob), but dont be afraid, just ask here, there are a lot of good people in this internet society who will answer politely even your silliest question about math

Comment: @Rizky Reza Fujisaki There's a stack exchange specifically for LaTeX questions, so I would suggest asking [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: wow thank you, I am just new active member in math stackexchange (I made the account long time ago, but almost didnt do anything), I never knew before that latex stackexchange is exist, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX is the gold standard for typesetting mathematics. Just install [MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/download) and you're ready to go. I personally prefer [TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) to the default editor (TeXworks) provided with MiKTeX, but there's plenty of options to chose from. Also, if you can't remember what the command is for some given symbol, [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is very useful.

Comment: It may be worth noting that we use a variant of LaTeX to typeset mathematics on this site. With a little practice, and sometimes cutting and pasting (but always carefully!), you can write math in LaTeX almost as easily as by hand. (Or so it seems to me.)